# execution sequential in node

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, busy-waiting

I have a function in nodejs, whose instructions must be executed sequentially. I've tried the native options (async and await) for node 8 and promises. I can not make him wait for FindOne results before returning.

```
module.existe = function(usr, pass) {

  (async() => {

    await coleccion.findOne(
      { usr: usr, pass: pass },
      (err, result) => {
        return (result == null)? false : true;
      }
    );

  })();
}
```

the query to mongo is fine, I can recover the document, but always after returning, so the validation does not work. what this function should do is check if a set {usr, key} already exists in the database

What can be?

Comment: coleccion.findOne is type (<options>, <fn<err, result>>)->(undefined) and you can't await undefined.  You need a function of type (<options>)->(<promise<result>) so you can await the result.  You can use util.promisify to convert.  so `coleccion.findOneAsync = promisify(coleccion.findOne); const result = await coleccion.findOneAsync({usr, pass});`

Comment: This is basically a dup of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).  You cannot return it directly because the function will return BEFORE the result is available.  So, you either return a promise or use a callback.  One of those two mechanisms can be used to communicate back the result.  Javascript will not "wait" for the async value before the function returns.  Even `async` and `await` will NOT do that for you.

Comment: thank you very much @jfriend00 the answer was in the link you quoted. There was no way to work because I had a conceptual error. instead of waiting for the return of the function I must wait for the callback. thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[generalhenry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491845/generalhenry) has already answered in the comments

Just making them altogether:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

module.existe = function (usr, pass) {
    const findOnePromise = promisify(coleccion.findOne);

    (async () => {
        const result = await findOnePromise({ usr: usr, pass: pass });
        return (result === null) ? false : true;
    })();
}
```

Docs: [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) - [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: This doesn't solve anything.  And, `findOne()` already has a promise interface so there's no reason to promisify it.  See what this question has been marked a dup of.  The issue is that you cannot make Javascript wait for an async value before the function returns.  You just can't.  So, you have to use either a callback or a promise and use those to communicate back the async result.  Mongodb's `.findOne()` already has a promise interface - no need to create a new one.